# Computing a probability

Tags: cryptanalysis, symmetric, pseudo-random-function

Let $(w_1,\cdots,w_l) \in (\{0,1\}^\lambda)^l$, and  $r_1,\cdots,r_l $ are  chosed as uniformly random from $Z^*_q$ such that $r_1+\cdots+r_l=0$ and $q$ is a large prime number. Also,  Let $F$is a pseudorandom function with key $k$. What value apear in place "?" in below relation (in o.w. part )?

$Pr[F_k(w_1)\cdot r_1+\cdots+F_k(w_l)\cdot r_l=0] := 
\begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if } (w_1=w_2=\cdots=w_l) \\
   ? & \text{o.w.} 
 \end{cases}$

Comment: Are you asking what "o.w." might mean ("otherwise")?  Or, are you asking for the value what would appear in place of "?" ?

Comment: Also, is the computed probability over a uniformly distributed set of $r_i$ values (constrained by the specified relations), or are you looking for a relation that would hold for any set of $r_i$ values that satisfy the relation?  If the latter, then we can come up with a second case ($r_1 = r_3 = 1, r_2 = r_4 = q-1$, $w_1 = w_2 \ne w_3 = w_4$ where the probability is 1

Comment: Thanks a lot, $r_i$s are from a uniformly distributed set, and we want to compute what value apear in place of '?'.

Comment: The answer will depend very heavily on $q,$ namely its factorisation. And you have a $k$ in your definition of a random function. What is this $k$?Please enter your comments above directly into the question so it is more readable.

Comment: I applied the mentioned notes into the question.

Comment: It appears to be bounded by a value that is slightly larger than $2/q$, but I couldn't come up with an exact derivation.  BTW: are the $r_i$ values actually chosen from $\mathbb{Z}^*_q$ (that is, the value 0 is excluded)?  Or, are they chosen from $\mathbb{Z}_q$?

Comment: Thanks poncho. yes $r_i$ values are from $Z^*_q$. Please write your calculation steps?